# Nested Static Linked Libraries and a Spooky Bug

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14, static-linking, clang++

(Platform: C++14, Clang 3.8, Ubuntu 16.04, CMake 3.5.1)

I have two static libraries (PawLIB, CalikoCat), and an executable that relies on OtherLibrary. Within CalkoCat is a single class, Dummy. (I'm just making sure everything links right before we start serious development on this library.)

The Dummy class currently relies on a function from PawLIB for testing purposes.

**`calikocat-source/include/calikocat/dummy.hpp`**

```
#include "pawlib/iochannel.hpp"

class Dummy
{
    public:
        Dummy(){}
        static void speak();
        ~Dummy(){}
};
```

**`calikocat-source/src/dummy.cpp`**

```
#include "otherlibrary/dummy.hpp"

void Dummy::speak()
{
    pawlib::ioc << "Hello, world!" << pawlib::io_end;
}
```

No problems. It compiles and links correctly with CMake.

NOTE: You may safely assume all the variables in both CMakeLists.txt files in this question are carefully tested and working. I've triple-checked each.

**`calikocat-source/CMakeLists.txt` (snippet)**

```
include_directories(include)

# Include headers of dependencies.
include_directories(${PAWLIB_DIR}/include)

add_library(${TARGET_NAME} STATIC
    include/calikocat/dummy.hpp
    src/dummy.cpp
)

# Link against dependencies.
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${PAWLIB_DIR}/lib/libpawlib.a)
```

Now, I like including tester applications with my libraries, and this is no exception. In the repo, I separate the library and tester code into `calikocat-source` and `calikocat-tester` directories. I use CMake for the tester as well...

**`calikocat-tester/CMakeLists.txt` (snippet)**

```
include_directories(include)

# Include headers of dependencies.
include_directories(${PAWLIB_DIR}/include)
include_directories(../calikocat-source/include)

add_executable(calikocat-tester
    main.cpp
)

# Link against dependencies.
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CPGF_DIR}/lib/libcpgf.a)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${PAWLIB_DIR}/lib/libpawlib.a)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/../calikocat-source/lib/$<CONFIG>/libcalikocat.a)
```

**Whether this builds correctly depends entirely on the presence of a single line on `main.cpp`! Read below CAREFULLY.**

**`calikocat-tester/main.cpp`, WORKING VERSION**

```
#include <calikocat/dummy.hpp>
#include <pawlib/iochannel.hpp>

int main()
{
    pawlib::ioc << "Hello, world!" << pawlib::io_end;
    Dummy::speak();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this version works as expected, printing `Hello, world!` out to the terminal twice.

**`calikocat-tester/main.cpp`, NON-WORKING VERSION**

```
#include <calikocat/dummy.hpp>
#include <pawlib/iochannel.hpp>

int main()
{
    //pawlib::ioc << "Hello, world!" << pawlib::io_end;
    Dummy::speak();

    return 0;
}
```

This version of the file, where I comment out the line using PawLIB directly, does NOT compile. Here's the error...

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/Debug/calikocat-tester
../../../calikocat-source/lib/Debug/libcalikocat.a(dummy.cpp.o): In function `Dummy::speak()':
/home/jason/Code/Repositories/calikocat/calikocat-source/src/dummy.cpp:4: undefined reference to `pawlib::ioc'
/home/jason/Code/Repositories/calikocat/calikocat-source/src/dummy.cpp:5: undefined reference to `pawlib::iochannel::operator<<(pawlib::ioformat::IOControl const&)'
../../../calikocat-source/lib/Debug/libcalikocat.a(dummy.cpp.o): In function `pawlib::iochannel::operator<<(char const*)':
/home/jason/Code/Repositories/calikocat/calikocat-source/../../pawlib/pawlib/include/pawlib/iochannel.hpp:521: undefined reference to `pawlib::iochannel::resolve_pointer(char const*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/calikocat-tester.dir/build.make:99: recipe for target '../../bin/Debug/calikocat-tester' failed
```

I am *expecting* it to compile, and when run, just print out `Hello, world!` to the terminal once.

What is going on here, and what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try reversing these two lines:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${PAWLIB_DIR}/lib/libpawlib.a)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/../calikocat-source/lib/$<CONFIG>/libcalikocat.a)
```

Because libcalikocat.a is using symbols from libpawlib.a, it should appear first on the command line.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. So, in other words, if `D` relies on `C`, `C` on `B`, and `B` on `A`, then `D` should link in the order of `C B A`. That's easy enough.